# warning when creating boxplot with nans in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns. One of the columns contains one nan value. Creating a histogram gives no warnings, but creating a boxplot gives a numpy VisibleDeprecationWarning. I use this in class and it worked fine the last couple of years. Advantage of pandas was always that hist and boxplot worked on data with nans. Current version that throws the error: numpy 1.19.1. pandas 1.1.0. Is this the intended behavior? Mismatch between versions? Example code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame()
data['test1'] = np.random.normal(size=100)
data['test2'] = np.random.normal(size=100)
data.test1[5] = np.nan  # set one value to nan
data.boxplot() # throws VisibleDeprecationWarning
```

Warning:
`/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:83: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)`

Comment: Your code works for me, giving the following [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d4dJhoZfo0OXCmiajrdw6DlekerXeud1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: what versions of numpy and pandas are you using? I am afraid it may be a version combo problem.

Comment: Numpy 1.18.5 and Pandas 1.1.1

Comment: Warning disappeared when updated to numpy 1.19.2 and pandas 1.1.3. So that is the easy solution. So if anybody runs into the warning, try updating.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of numpy 1.19.1. pandas 1.1.0 gives the warning. Warning disappears after updating to latest version (in this case numpy 1.19.2 and pandas 1.1.3).